# Where Can I Find Literary Agents That Represent Christian Fiction?

Tags: publishing, agent

I have been trying to find suitable literary agents for three years that feel comfortable representing Christian fiction. I have four unpublished and thoroughly reviewed novels ready to be published, but I would to publish them one-by-one. I was wondering if anybody can assist me in finding literary agents that feel comfortable representing Christian works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do targeted searches on http://agentquery.com . It's a free service, and very comprehensive.

My own experience, however, is that Christian fiction is a particularly tough area to break into. The agents and houses that specialize in that area tend to have certain very specific things they are looking for.

Comment: That's very insightful. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

Duotrope.com has started to include agents in their listings. I don't see "Christian" as a category but you could probably use some of the other selections to narrow your search and then do research from there.

Answer (score 1):

The Christian Writer's Market Guide has long been a resource for Christians: [https://www.amazon.com/Christian-Writers-Market-Guide-2020/dp/1621840662](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1621840662)

Comment: I'll consider buying that.

Answer (score 1):

[Stephen Lawhead](https://www.stephenlawhead.com) writes in these genres (Christian Fantasy*) and uses a couple of literary agents:

1. https://www.greenburger.com/
2. http://abnerstein.co.uk/

Check those out and then try this:

1. Think of an author you like
2. Google or better (https://duckduckgo.com) for `<author-name> literary agent`

*See [Hood trilogy by Stephen Lawhead](https://amzn.to/33G6ryH)

Also [In the Region of the Summer Stars: Eirlandia, Book One (Eirlandia Series 1)](https://amzn.to/3aajR8q)

Comment: I went ahead and queried his agent! Thanks for the resource!